# What were the wishes Disney's Aladdin made?

Tags: disney, aladdin, aladdin-1992

What were the three wishes Aladdin made in the Disney animated feature film?

Bonus points if you can give the time mark they happened.

Answer (score 17):

Aladdin's three wishes are:

- "*Genie, I wish for you to make me a prince*" - **43:55**
- "*Genie, I want you to save my life*" - **1:01:00**
- "*I wish for your freedom*" - **1:19:30**

For the record, the second one is a fudge, he doesn't wish it, the *Genie* says it and Aladdin's head flops forward. Also he makes a non-wish at **38:46** when he tricks the genie into taking him out of the cave.

[image: The genie puffs his chest out with his arms extended; his left arm is thrust towards the camera with three fingers raised; in the background we see 6 other "genies" looking at the main genie]

---

For the sake of completeness, *Jafar's* three wishes are:

- "*I wish to rule on high, a sultan!*" - **1:07:45**
- "*I wish to be the most powerful sorceror in the world!!*" - **1:09:00**
- "*I wish to be an all-powerful genie!!!*" - **1:17:00**

Jafar also makes a fourth wish ("*I wish for Princess Jasmine to fall desperately in love with me*" at **1:12:57**) but it's not within the Genie's power to grant it.

---

In the sequel, [*Aladdin II - The Return of Jafar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Return_of_Jafar), Genie/Jafar also grants two wishes to Abis Mal:

- "*I wish for the legendary sunken treasure ship of Cœur du Mer*" - **21:55**
- "*Perhaps you wish me to return you to the desert?*" - **22:18**

In the post-credit stinger, Abis asks "*Does this mean I don't get my third wish?*" (at **1:06:05**)

[image: Abis holds the lamp in his left hand; his right hand is raised and pointed; he looks in that direction confused asking the above quote]

Comment: Way to go for the "bonus" points :P

Comment: Silly genie.  He could've freed himself anytime :)

Comment: Here's an extra bonus Aladdin wish: "I wish for the Nile." - ~1:20:00, I don't have an exact timestamp.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo No, no, no. It was "I wish for *de* Nile."